Cohomology class of automorphism group of Galois twist
I've asked this question on Math.SE but didn't receive any answers.
Let $\Gamma$ be the Galois group of a finite Galois extension $K/k$ of fields of characteristic zero. Let $G$ be an algebraic group defined over $k$. Let $G'$ be another algebraic group over $k$. We say that $G'$ is a $K/k$-form of $G$ if $G_K$ and $G'_K$ are isomorphic. It is well-known that the $K/k$-forms of $G$ are in natural bijection with the pointed Galois cohomology set $H^1(\Gamma, \operatorname{Aut}G(K))$. The trivial cohomology class corresponds to $G$ itself.
Now consider (assuming they exist) the automorphism group schemes $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ and $\operatorname{Aut}(G')$. The latter is clearly a $K/k$-form of the former, so both correspond to classes in $H^1(\Gamma, \operatorname{Aut(Aut} G(K)))$. What is the cohomology class of $\operatorname{Aut}(G')$?
I assume that it arises as the image of the class of $G'$ in $H^1(\Gamma, \operatorname{Aut}G(K))$ along the map induced by conjugation $G \to \operatorname{Aut}(G)$, but I'm not quite sure. Can we characterise those forms of $G$ which map to zero under this map of cohomology groups?
I'm interested in answers concerning descent in a more general context too.

Aren’t algebraic groups which are isomorphic over a finite extension already isomorphic over $k$? Since they both have $k$-rational points they are trivial torsors. Perhaps you only intend for $G’$ to become an algebraic group upon base change to $K$?

@Vik78 Are you sure that's true? Take the Weil $\operatorname{Res}_{\mathbb C/\mathbb R}(\mathbb G_m)$ compared to $\mathbb G_m \times \mathbb G_m$. Their $\mathbb R$-points are not isomorphic while their $\mathbb C$-points are.

I think it is indeed the image of the original cohomology class under the map $G\to Aut(G)$ given by conjugation. It is convenient to show this using the formalism of torsors. So the form $G'$ correponds to the $Aut(G)$-torsor of isomorphisms $Isom(G,G')$. The torsor corresponding to $Aut(G')$ is the torsor of isomorphisms $Isom(Aut(G),Aut(G)')$. Now, there is a general criterion for a map of groups $H\to H'$ to carry the cohomology class of a torsor $P$ to the cohomology class of the torsor $P'$: all you need is the existence of a map $P\to P'$ which intertwines the $H$ and $H'$ actions.
In the current situation, such a map is obvious to construct: every isomorphism $\varphi\colon G\to G'$ (over a field extension) gives an isomorphism $Aut(G)\to Aug(G')$ by $\psi \mapsto \varphi^{-1} \circ \psi \circ \varphi$. You can now check that this association indeed intertwines the actions of $G$ and $Aut(G)$ on the torsors so it witnesses the fact that the cocycle of $Aut(G')$ is the image of the cocycle of $G'$.
